# How to make a tkinter entry default value permanent

Tags: python, tkinter, widget, permanent, tkinter-entry

I am writing a program in python that will take in specific formats, a Phone number and dollar/cent values. How can I make tkinter have default value which is permanent, not deletable. For example (XXX)-XXX-XXXX?

basically you can add an entry to the widget but the entry is defined the permanent value like when its empty it looks like (_ _ _)-___-____ when it has text it looks like (434)-332-1234

Comment: You're going to have to explain a little bit more about what you mean by a default value that is permanent and not deletable, and yet an `Entry`.

Comment: basically you can add an entry to the widget but the entry is defined the permanent value like when its empty it looks like (_ _ _)-___-____ when it has text it looks like (434)-332-1234

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want some sort of template in which a user can type his/her information but is restricted to some format. You can do this using the Entry's `validatecommand`. Basically, this calls a function whenever something is being inserted and can return True or False to accept or reject the change. For more information about how this works see [this answer by Bryan Oakley](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4140988/3714930).

In your case, you'd want the function to return True whenever something has the format `(...)-...-....`, which you can check with a regular expression. The regular expression you could use is `^\(\d{0,3}\)-\d{0,3}-\d{0,4}$`.
I'll explain it for you. `^`  means that that should be the beginning of the string, `\(` means there should be a `(`, `\d{0,3}` means that there can be 0 to 3 numbers (I assumed you only want numbers, if not you can change it to `\w` to accept any letter or number). Then comes `\)` which means `)`, a `-` which literally means `-`, some digits and a `-` again and at the end a `$` which means that should be the end of the string.

You can use this regular expression in the `validatecommand` function to check if the entry has the right format by using:

```
import Tkinter as tk
import re

class MyApp():
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = tk.Tk()

        vcmd = (self.root.register(self.OnValidate), '%P')
        self.entry = tk.Entry(self.root, validate="key", 
                              validatecommand=vcmd)
        self.entry.pack()
        self.prog = re.compile('^\(\d{0,3}\)-\d{0,3}-\d{0,4}$')
        self.entry.insert(0, '()--')
        self.root.mainloop()

    def OnValidate(self, P):
        if self.prog.match(P):
            result = True
        else:
            result = False

        return result

app=MyApp()
```

I used the before linked answer as template, removed everything that you don't need for your particular case and inserted the regular expression. Because it only returns True when the string matches the pattern, only edits that fit in the pattern are allowed.

Comment: This doesn't give a very good user experience. As a user you don't see the actual template and have no idea what you're supposed to enter.

Comment: Yeah that's true. This was a first draft, considering the question not being really clear on what the exact behavior should be, but the complete lack of feedback by the OP kinda stopped me from wanting to improve it. Maybe I'll improve it sometime. I mostly linked here from that other question because I was surprised that the question was almost exactly the same and only two days old.