# Forcing formatted text in entry widget

Tags: tkinter, format, tkinter-entry

Is there a way to "force" the format of text in a tkinter (or any) entry widget? For example, some forms online, when entering in your phone number, come pre-formatted with `(___)___-____` and only allow 10 number entries. Is there a way to do this in python?

Comment: Almost exactly the same question was asked [two days ago](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30022059/3714930), I gave an answer using `validatecommand` there. Of course, as Bryan Oakley mentions, there are several options, depending on the exact behavior that you want.

Comment: Thank you, I am going to read into it!

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing built-in, but the entry widget has enough functionality to allow you to build it yourself.

For example, if the template is "xxx-xxxx", you can set a binding that automatically inserts a dash when three characters are detected, and you can also set up input validation that only allows numbers in the first three positions.

You can see a simple example in an article published by packt publishing. See the article [Miscellaneous Tips](https://www.packtpub.com/books/content/miscellaneous-tips), and search for "Formatting widget data"

A simpler solution is to use three entry widgets along with labels for the parts that are required.

Comment: I appreciate it. I am concerned with the approach, I like to know how things are done more than is there built in functionality.